# Can a graph find the shortest route from one vertex to another in two directions?

Tags: graph

I am trying to create a graph and fill it with cities, the distances between them and then find the fastest route from one city to another. I am new to graphs and I have decided to search online for similar algorithms. One which I have found has brought this question to me. The algorithm which I have found uses Dijkstra's Algorithm to find the shortest possible path from one vertex to another. However, it only works for some cases. I was able to find that this algorithm keeps track of the INs and OUTs a vertex had. This meant that if there is a path from A to B and from B to C the algorithm was able to find the path from A to C, however it is unable to find the path from C to A (or from C to B for that matter). I added a bit of code to change the algorithm in such a way that when an edge was added from one vertex to another it also added an edge from the other vertex to the one we were adding the edge to. This however made the algorithm not work for any cases. Part of my code for further explanation:

```
graph.add("a", "b", 32);
graph.add("a", "c", 15);
graph.add("a", "d", 17)
graph.add("b", "c", 17);
graph.add("c", "d", 10); 
graph.add("c", "e", 21);
graph.add("d", "e", 22);
graph.add("b", "f", 11);
graph.add("a", "f", 123);
graph.add("e", "f", 8);
graph.add("d","f", 5);
graph.add("c", "g", 19);
graph.add("e", "g", 4);
graph.add("b", "g", 12);
```

INs and OUTs for each vertex (pre alteration):

```
Vertex: a :  In: Out: b c d f 
Vertex: b :  In: a Out: c f g 
Vertex: c :  In: a b Out: d e g 
Vertex: d :  In: a c Out: e f 
Vertex: e :  In: c d Out: f g 
Vertex: f :  In: b a e d Out: 
Vertex: g :  In: c e b Out:
```

The original algorithm will successfully find the shortest for cases vertices point from one to another. Example:

```
a to e
a : cost : 0
c : cost : 15
e : cost : 36
```

However it will fail if we try to find a path from vertex which does not point back to an vertex which is already pointing at it, making finding paths from vertices added later to vertices added at the start impossible.

```
e to a
No path found
```

INs and OUTs for each vertex (after alteration):

```
Vertex: a :  In: b c d f Out: b c d f 
Vertex: b :  In: a c f g Out: a c f g 
Vertex: c :  In: a b d e g Out: a b d e g 
Vertex: d :  In: a c e f Out: a c e f 
Vertex: e :  In: c d f g Out: c d f g 
Vertex: f :  In: b a e d Out: b a e d 
Vertex: g :  In: c e b Out: c e b
```

I believed if I was able to make the vertices point back to the vertices which are pointing in them that the algorithm would work, however every attempt now leaves me with a null pointer exception.

This has led me to the following questions:

Are graphs where each vertex pointing to all of its adjacent vertices has the same vertices pointing back at it actually a thing and is there a specific name for them? Image for clarification.

Is Dijkstra's Algorithm not the correct algorithm to use for this particular case?

The previously mentioned algorithm I found and am using is here, credits to snarkbait: https://gist.github.com/snarkbait/9ff6fffe423b220c8890

[image: two muppets]

Answer (score 0):

You can consider such a graph as *symmetric directed graph* or simply as *undirected graph* (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph)). And Dijkstra's algorithm in general must process this case pretty good.